# How to set ip valid for ftp sever

Tags: ftp

I ran into a problem.I'm using IIS and where should i set it?
I'm setting `ftp server 2016`.I upload my files by `FileZila` and it works and I Can connect and watch my files.
I don't know how to build `IP valid` for it.

Comment: This question is [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open IIS, Change 'All unassigned' to the outside IP address you will be using (might have to enter it manually)
This will force the FTP site to only listen on the right IP address and should respond using the same address.